# I want to install an apk file in android but it not work (without INTENT)

Tags: android, installation

I want to install program update.
my code is:

```
private void installApk(File file) {

        if(file.exists()){
            try {   
                final String command = "pm install -r " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    }
```

permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

signed my app with signAPK.
this program not work.please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot install an apk by command line. adb is just a tool. "adb" and "install" is not shell command. Please refer to this answer if you would like to install apk. [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)